# Covert array date string and decrease 3 hours in Shell Script

Tags: arrays, linux, shell

I need from an array decrease 3 hours from it and print in command line again

the output of the array is:

```
12:29:14 
14:10:26 
14:30:34 
14:35:31 
14:35:10 
11:57:03 
12:49:31 
12:57:09 
11:04:49 
13:06:57 
14:35:34 
14:30:49 
14:34:28 
12:58:02 
14:28:12 
12:29:18 
11:33:23 
12:27:04 
14:35:43 
12:58:46
```

I am trying with this line, but no use.

```
date2=$(date  -d "${array[@]}" "3 hour ago" +"%H:%M:%S")
```

Could you please help me about  it?

Comment: please check [ask] and provide a [mcve] so we can understand what is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
times=( "12:29:14" "14:10:26" "14:30:34" "14:35:31" "14:35:10" "11:57:03" "12:49:31" "12:57:09" "11:04:49" "13:06:57" "14:35:34" "14:30:49" "14:34:28" "12:58:02" "14:28:12" "12:29:18" "11:33:23" "12:27:04" "14:35:43" "12:58:46")

for dateItem in ${times[@]}
do
date2=$(date --date="$dateItem 3 hour ago" +%H:%M:%S)
echo $date2
done
```

Comment: I've tried friend it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi It's worked after doing some changes it works correct,

If you wish todo it without an array 
Here it is:

```
date2=$(date  -d "$times 3 hour ago" +"%H:%M:%S")
echo $date2
```